# unknown extra space source in staggered grid view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, staggered-gridview

this is my first time to use cards i got some extra space don't know where it comes from

this is my card view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/product_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/sample_1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/product_image"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/product_image"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="$0.00"
        android:textColor="#000000" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_description"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/product_image"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#CCFFFFFF"
        android:text="This is the product description!"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here's my space decoration class

```
public class SpacesDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
private final int mSpace;

public SpacesDecoration(int space) {
    this.mSpace = space;
}

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {

    if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0)
        outRect.top = mSpace;
}}}
```

and that's the final view i get
 [image: and here's what i get]

can anybody tell me where's this extra space come from , thanks in advance

Comment: What extra space? Your items wrap content and the first one is offset from the top. That's what your code says, that's what it does, and that's what we can see in your screenshot. What is it that you don't understand?

Comment: the white space where it comes from that's my question

Comment: Check my answer below. Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems in your `CardView` XML.

**1.** Update `ImageView` attribute `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_width="match_parent"`.

**2.** Use `android:src="@drawable/sample_1"` in your `ImageView` instead of `card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/sample_1"` and also use `scaleType` as per your needs.

**3.** Add attribute `card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"` to `CardView` and also use `card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false"`

**FYI**, I have removed some unnecessary `attributes` from `TextView's` and added some to give proper alignment.

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/product_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/sample_1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="$0.00"
            android:textColor="#000000" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/product_image"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:background="#CCFFFFFF"
            android:text="This is the product description!"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Comment: well i edited the xml and removed the space decorator and i got this https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzxwVA95DE56Tk5MZE1TaXVaMFE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Use imageview width match parent. I have already mentioned in my answer.

Comment: well this screenshot with imageview width match parent , it looks really good in my card view preview , but when i run it it gives me the view in the image

Comment: Try my answer fully. Attached is the screenshot from my mobile. Use image scaletype centercrop

Comment: i tried your code it worked but i needed to set the scaleType to fitXY to give me the desired View

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. If its seems useful, don't forget to give an up-vote. Thanks in advance :)